# Required Field Validator gets clear on postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a clear button and save button ,when i press clear button the required field icon gets clear as the button gets postback,i dont want this to happen i want to show the icon even after clear button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify validation group attribute name for the save button, and set this name on required  field validation control

```
ValidationGroup="validation_name"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but even after specifing validation group for save and required field validator control the icon gets clear on postback on clear button

Comment: you have also to specifying the name of validation group into the required field validator control , if it is not working yet ! please show me your tags

Comment: <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dt_To"
                                            Display="Static" ErrorMessage="<img src=../../images/15warning.png>" ForeColor="Red"
                                            ToolTip="Select To Date" ValidationGroup="v"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: <telerik:RadButton ID="btnClearDate" runat="server" OnClick="btnClearDate_Click2"
                                            Text="Clear" Width="90px">
                                        </telerik:RadButton>

Comment: Here are 2 buttons when i click on btnClearDate the required field validator gets clear as the button gets postback

Comment: As i tell you before modify your clear button as following :

<telerik:RadButton ID="btnClearDate" runat="server" OnClick="btnClearDate_Click2" Text="Clear" Width="90px"  ValidationGroup="v" > </telerik:RadButton